# Retrieve all metadata fields of a document in the search - elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to retrieve all the metadata fields that a document has in the elasticsearch. Is there a way to force the query to show them all in the search results?

```
ex:

GET /search-test/_search
{
"fields": ["_id","_doc_count","_field_names","_ignored","_index","_meta"],
   "query": {
    "bool":{
    "must":[
        {"match" : { "_id":"11085" }}
      ]
  }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with `*` on `_source` field like this?

```
GET /search-test/_search
{
  "_source": ["*"],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"match" : { "_id":"11085" }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**OR** with `"_source": true`

```
GET search-test/_search
{
  "_source": true, 
  "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {"match" : { "_id":"11085" }}
          ]
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: This gives all the fields with in "_source" which is one of the metadata fields. Similar to this field, I am trying to see is there a way to view what's in other other metadata fields of the documents.

Answer (score 0):

It by default shows all the results.

If you want a particular result then add "include":["_id","_doc_count","_field_names","_ignored","_index","_meta"]

```
GET /search-test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool":{
    "must":[
        {"match" : { "_id":"11085" }}
      ]
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am seeing only _id, _index and _source. Does it mean, this document has no other metadata fields ?